# When someone substitutes for someone else

Tags: word-meaning, verbs

I wonder in the following sentence:

> -1- **Dayton** was substituted for **Williams** in the second half of the game. [[Source]](https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/substitute)

Dayton enters the game or exits the game?

The same goes with:

> -2- The coach substituted **Dayton** for **Williams**.

Comment: It's ambiguous—it can be taken either way. Although, I'd say that, more often than not, it would be interpreted as, in this case, Dayton entering the game and Williams leaving. (But it doesn't have to.)

Comment: Is it the normal way that each native would convey the same meaning Jason? I mean normally the listener would  recognize by observing the happening (him/her) or ther is a safer way to say that?

Comment: I would generally agree with @JasonBassford, except I don't think the ambiguity is very strong. In my experience, I have never heard either 1 or 2 and the meaning was 'Dayton was in, was removed, and Williams went in'. I have heard the opposite meaning many times. One could remove the very minor ambiguity in a number of ways. Here is one: The coach put Dayton in for Williams. And another: Dayton was put in for Williams . . . .

Comment: Or *Dayton was **the substitute** for Williams*. In that syntax, the noun *substitute* replaces the original. Which, now that I think of it, could also be alternate phrasing: *Dayton **replaced** Williams* or *the coach **replaced** Dayton with Williams*.